# Using generative models for classification

Tags: classification, generative-models

I think I never saw a generative model used for a classification task: usually a discriminative model is used; Sometimes (AFAIK, with deep neural networks) a generative model is created as a pre-training step, but then it is used to build a discriminative model - which usually performs better in classification tasks.

Can we use `P(Y=label,X=data)` to classify any given data using a generative model? How are generative models used in classification tasks? If they are not used, why is it so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generative model is widely used!

Here are some widely used examples

- Naive Bayes
- Mixture of Gaussian
- Bayesian Network (and other probablistic graphical models)
- ... many more

Your math is incorrect. For **both generative model and discriminate model we are trying to get** $P(Y|X)$.

- Discriminate model directly gets $P(Y|X)$ from data.
- Generative model gets $P(Y|X)$ from the joint $P(X,Y)$, and the joint is calculated from $P(Y)$ and $P(X|Y)$.

Here is the intuitive explanation: let us assume we want to use a car's weight, to predict the car's transmission type, i.e., manual or automatic. (check `mtcars[,c('wt','am')]` in R to see how data looks like.)

- The discriminate model will think about where should we set the threshold on weight to have better results. And setting the threshold is essentially specify $P(Y|X)$.
- Generative model will first look at training data for how may manual car and automatic car we have (This is $P(Y)$) and what's the characteristic/weights of for different cars (This is $P(X|Y)$), and eventually calculate $P(Y|X)$.

Comment: I have a follow-up question here. On "A practical guide to training restricted Boltzmann machines" (Hinton), he discusses about RBM for classification. One of the 3 proposed methods is to train a RBM with a joint probability distribution (presenting both data and labels as input), then, to find the right class, he states that one can fix the test input and try with different labels, to find the one with maximum probability. The sum of there probabilities will not be 1, but it seems a valid strategy to me. Why do you say that we need `P(Y|X)`, but he proposes a solution without it?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, $P(Y|X)=P(X,Y)/P(X)$, but in Hinton solution it is not necessary to find the normalization factor $P(X)$, which is constant for any class tested anyway, so $P(Y|X)\propto P(X,Y)$ can be used to classify.